# Issue with building service in liferay7?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I got error while deloying my servicebuilder project in liferay 7. The error is as follows:-

```
Problem with deploying bundle: Could not resolve module: abhishek-service [497]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.example.exception; version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"
```

I could not figure out why this problem came? The steps I followed are as follows:-
1) Made a servicebuilder through liferay ide named 'abhishek'.
2) Leave the default namespace and entity as it is in service.xml in abhishek-services folder.
3) Build the service through BuildService option in Gradle window.
4) Deployed abhishek-service onto the server.
5) Error pops up as mentioned above.
Please help..thanx in advance..

Comment: Does the same error pop up when building service through ant?Any luck with code 497

Comment: Could you share your service.xml? OSGi is failing to find thes package `com.example.exception`, we need now to figure why...

Answer (score 0):

I guess:

- `com.example.exception` was generated by service builder and placed in `abhishek-api` module.
- you only deployed `abhishek-service` module

Try to deploy `abhishek-api` module as well.